# Value of DataList sourced from JavaScript returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-datalist

I'm creating a datalist on my webpage that sources it's values from a JavaScript array (that sources from a Java array using JSP).

Here is my code for populating the data list:

```
<input name="Engineer Name" list="engineer" />
<datalist id="engineer"></datalist>
<script>
  //Take the engineers array and transfer to javascript array
  //This is so we can source the Engineer Drop-Down menu from a file dynamically
  var engineerArray = [];
  <% for (int i=0; i<engineers.size(); i++) { %>
  engineerArray[<%= i %>] = "<%= engineers.get(i) %>";
  <% } %>

  for (var i in engineerArray) {
    var datalist = document.getElementById('engineer');
    datalist.innerHTML += '<option value=' + engineerArray[i] + '>';
  }
</script>
```

This code displays the datalist correctly, but on submission of the form I call another JavaScript function that contains the line:

```
var engineer = document.getElementById('engineer').value;
```

And that value ends up being `undefined`.

Comment: What is the dom type of 'engineer' ? Can you provide the html code piece.

Comment: I edited the html code piece. let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the value of datalist incorrectly. The selector has to be on the `input` element. I have modified the code for reference:

```
<input name="Engineer Name" id="engineerList" list="engineer" />
<datalist id="engineer"></datalist>
<script>
  //Take the engineers array and transfer to javascript array
  //This is so we can source the Engineer Drop-Down menu from a file dynamically
  var engineerArray = [];
  <% for (int i=0; i<engineers.size(); i++) { %>
  engineerArray[<%= i %>] = "<%= engineers.get(i) %>";
  <% } %>

  for (var i in engineerArray) {
    var datalist = document.getElementById('engineer');
    datalist.innerHTML += '<option value=' + engineerArray[i] + '>';
  }
</script>
```

Then get the datalist value by specifying the correct `id`:

```
var engineer = document.getElementById('engineerList').value;
```